# How to connect to RabbitMQ server with TLS without certificate in Node

Tags: ssl, openssl, rabbitmq, tls1.2, tls1.3

I need help connecting to RabbitMQ with TLS using Node.

The client gave us credentials for connecting to their RabbitMQ server.

They say we don’t need any certificates for TLS connection, and I’m using NodeJS.

We’re getting this error.
`OperationalError: certificate has expired`

We’re trying to use this Node client library https://github.com/amqp-node/amqplib and in their SSL guide(https://amqp-node.github.io/amqplib/ssl.html) it’s written

```
If you're not going to use a client certificate, you need only to make sure you will trust the server certificate:
var opts = {
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('cacert.pem')]
};
```

this is our current code

```
const conn = await connect({
    hostname: process.env.RABBITMQ_HOST,
    port: Number(process.env.RABBITMQ_PORT),
    username: process.env.RABBITMQ_USER,
    password: process.env.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD,
    vhost: process.env.RABBITMQ_VHOST,
    protocol: 'amqps',
  }
```